# Trying to understand why Sn2 is not possible in this reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I am trying to understand why the red Br doesn't react? Is it because there can't be a flip of groups? Or steric hindrance?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6404/will-bridged-compounds-undergo-sn1-reaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backside attack on the red bromide is not possible. The rest of the norbornyl skeleton completely blocks the trajectory required for $\mathrm{S}_{N}2$ reaction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If possible, I would like to ask you this question: would the reaction if there were no bridge in the middle? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Because then, it would just be cyclohexane. As long as you could access the conformation where the red bromide group is axial, you could have a productive substitution reaction.

Comment: Excellent answer by Zhe. I'd also like to point out that the red Br is on a tertiary carbon anyway - makes SN2 nearly impossible.